# How to write a Rails polymorphic association query with a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have a many to many relationship through a polymorphic association and I'm having trouble writing my query

Here's my migration:

```
  def change
    create_table :excuses do |t|
      t.string :label
      t.integer :status, default: 0, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :excuses_excusables do |t|
      t.references :excusable, polymorphic: true, index: true, null: false
      t.integer :excuse_id, index: true, null: false
    end
  end
```

The idea is that I can associate an `Excuse` to one of my existing tables, `re_evalutations` such that from the `re_evaluation` I can call `re_evaluation.excuse`.  Excuses are pre-defined set of excuses that a User will choose from which is why I went the many-to-many route.

The part that I cannot figure out is how to call `excuse.re_evaluations` to be able to fetch all `re_evaluations` with a given `excuse`.

```
class ReEvaluation < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :excuses_excusable, as: :excusable
  has_one :excuse, through: :excuses_excusable
end

class Excuse < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :excuses_excusables, foreign_key: :excuse_id
    
    # Does not work
    # has_many :re_evaluations, through: :excuses_excusables, source_type: "ReEvaluation"
end

class ExcusesExcusable < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :excusable, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :excuse
end
```

How can I modify these associations to allow me to call `excuse.re_evaluations`?

Comment: I think there should be at least the `source: :excusable` atrribute in your `#Does not work` line (in addition to those which are already there)

Comment: Can you write out the whole line?

Comment: I posted it in an answer.

Comment: Like to point out if you need to go the other way you can use: (put in class ExcusesExcusable )
`belongs_to :re_evaluation, -> { where(ExcusesExcusable: { excusable_type: 'ReEvaluation' }) }, foreign_key: 'excusable_id'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You correctly used the `source_type` attribute to specify correct type filter on your polymorphic association. However the source association (`excusable`) cannot be inferred from the associotion name (`re_evaluations`) and you need to specify it explicitly (`source: :excusable`).

Therefore if you modify your code like this, it should work:

```rb
has_many :re_evaluations, through: :excuses_excusables, source: :excusable, source_type: "ReEvaluation"
```

Comment: omg.  I can't believe I missed that.  Thank you!